# how to full trust PayPalCoreSDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security, paypal

I want to full trust this assembly, but i've tried several things like trust in `web.config` but it keeps saying that is incorrect because of some virtual directory, which i don't have any.

**ERROR:**

> Attempt by security transparent method
>   'PayPal.UserAgentHeader.get_OperatingSystemFriendlyName()' to access
>   security critical method
>   'System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher..ctor(System.String)'
>   failed.
>
> Assembly 'PayPalCoreSDK, Version=1.4.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is partially trusted, which causes the CLR to
>   make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency
>   annotations in the assembly itself.  In order to access security
>   critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i needed a virtual directory configured in the application pool to let me config in the web.config.
After that it worked fine.